# position fixed outside on the container issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

what i'm trying to do is make a container that contain a fixed line in the middle what i want to do is to cut the line outside on the section

the problem with this divs and its styles :

HTML :

```
<div class="stem-wrapper">
    <div class="stem"></div>
    <div class="stem-background"></div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/userJ/pen/yvxLpK)

if you remove the background from **section header** you will see what i mean , i want to make the fixed only contain inside the section not outside of the container .

Comment: Can't find section_header

Comment: section header , sorry my bad without _

Comment: Sorry, but I have problems with understanding your question, but it seems that `overflow: hidden` on the container would fix all your problems.

Comment: i found a way with z-index and clip-path properties that fixed the problem , because overflow doesn't work with position : fixed property .

Comment: I didn't know that the overflow doesn't work with fixed. That's cool that we both learned something.